# How to preload external JS file with ads?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to preload a external JS file, so that the generated JS content appears first on page? I'd like to assure that my ads are already loaded when the page is shown to the user. Right now there is a small delay when loading ads from external JS, while the page content is already visible.

Comment: **Always** visible? Good luck.

Comment: Always load? Than you have to put it into the HTML itself. 'Always run' is another story.

Comment: I'm not fighting against AdBlock etc. I just want to assure that ads are already loaded when the page is visible to the user.

Comment: Why does it matter if the ads load before the page, or after the page? Once it's all loaded, it's all loaded.

Comment: No, because this JS snippet is counting pageviews. If the user is only a few seconds on the page and the JS is not loaded, then it doesn't increase the counter.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question I must know how the ads are being loaded. Some external JavaScript ad-loaders attach themselves to the `load` event of the DOM itself, which means they will not fire until the entire document has loaded. If you have control of the ad loader JavaScript, you could inject it into the DOM earlier, either by dropping the `<script>` into the location where it should end up in the `body` or by finding an event that happens before the document is completely loaded (which is dicey if the JS needs to use the DOM).

Either way, you're beholden to the time it takes the server to respond to the request for that JS and the time it takes the browser to process and render the result. In other words, you're taking an asynchronous request and forcibly making it synchronous, or "blocking".